# How to individually color characters in a header element while preserving that the element wraps as a single element when the view size shrinks?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Below is a header block I created, with a title stacked atop a *'navbar'*. If you look at the code, you'll see an `<h1>` tag that's wrapping two **(2)**  tags, and their contents — its fundamental (or essential) structure looks something like this:

```
    <h1>
        <div>
            <!-- Nested <span> tags --> 
        </div>

        <div>
            <!-- Nested <span> tags --> 
        </div>
    </h1>
```

---

#### The Issue

---

The issue is that when the view port is shrunk (which happens on mobile devices, obviously) the elements wrap in all crazy sorts of ways. The way it wraps, seems to be contingent on the view-port size, but nevertheless; it always wraps in a way that is most undesirable.
How can I make it wrap so that when the screen shrinks to the point where it has to wrap, the entire second word `OPINIONS` wraps, instead of just `pinions` or `bstract`?

---

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo|Cinzel&display=swap');
:root {
  --red-alpha: #7C000D;
  --red-beta: #9C0810;
  --charcoal: #060912;
}

body {
  background-color: #555;
}

#head-alpha {
  display: block;
  background-color: #808080;
  border: 2.5px ridge #500C12;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 18%;
  padding: 2.5px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
}

#head-beta {
  display: block;
  background-color: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #400;
  width: 400px;
  height: 18%;
  padding: 2.5px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
}

.xxl-a {
  color: var(--red-alpha);
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-right: -3px
}

.xxl-b {
  color: var(--charcoal);
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  border: 1.25px solid #88040C;
  height: 32px;
  background: #101218;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  color: var(--red-beta);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.lrg-fg {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>SOLO</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="head-alpha">
    <div>
      <span id="span_1" class="xxl-a">A</span>
      <span id="span_2" class="xxl-b">bstract</span>
      <span id="span_0" class="xxl-b">&nbsp</span>
      <span id="span_3" class="xxl-a">O</span>
      <span id="span_4" class="xxl-b">pinions</span>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <span class="lrg-fg">HOME &nbsp; • &nbsp; </span>
      <span class="lrg-fg">BLOG &nbsp; • &nbsp; </span>
      <span class="lrg-fg">UPDATES</span>
    </div>
  </h1>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <hr>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <h1 id="head-beta">
    <div>
      <span id="span_1" class="xxl-a">A</span>
      <span id="span_2" class="xxl-b">bstract</span>
      <span id="span_0" class="xxl-b">&nbsp</span>
      <span id="span_3" class="xxl-a">O</span>
      <span id="span_4" class="xxl-b">pinions</span>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <span class="lrg-fg">HOME &nbsp; • &nbsp; </span>
      <span class="lrg-fg">BLOG &nbsp; • &nbsp; </span>
      <span class="lrg-fg">UPDATES</span>
    </div>
  </h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector ::first-letter does exist, which should help you do this much more simply. You can just use a single span then. Usage is along the lines of

```
#span-1::first-letter {
  color: var(—A);
}
```

PS, the best practice for CSS is to not use IDs in selectors. Those tend to be left alone so the JavaScript can use them, and instead classes tend to be used.

Comment: I just threw the ID's in there so I could clearly reference them here on SOF. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all your "Abstract" and all your "Opinions" elements in a container and then wrap those in another container. Now you can apply `display: flex` and easily change the `flex-direction` when the screen width changes.

Comment: Okay Ill give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a div for Abstract and Opinions. Also declare a viewport in the head section. Use height 100% on html & body to make space for the #head height.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>SOLO</title>
<meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
<meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo|Cinzel&display=swap">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="head">
  <div>
    <span id="span_1" class="xxl-a">A</span>
    <span id="span_2" class="xxl-b">bstract</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="span_3" class="xxl-a">O</span>
    <span id="span_4" class="xxl-b">pinions</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use the flex-wrap to wrap the span's

```
:root {
  --A: #800;
  --B: #090909;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 1rem/1.5 'Cinzel', serif;
  background-color: #555;
}
#head {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18%;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid #400;
}
.xxl-a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3px;
  color: var(--A);
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-size: 55px;
}
.xxl-b {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3px;
  color: var(--B);
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-size: 55px;
}
div.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  border: 1px double #A00;
  background-color: #444;
}
```